# How to build Seo Urls in WebSphere Commerce inside Java in Websphere Commerce 7

Tags: websphere, websphere-commerce

Is there an easy way to build seo friendly urls inside a Java class within WebSphere Commerce 7 (Feature Pack 6).

In JSP files you can use the provided  tag, but is there also an easy way to build the seo urls inside a Java method.

I rebuild the tag methods in an own helper class but this seems to be a little over the top and can contain a lot of errors.

Does IBM provide helper classes which I haven´t found yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To create SEO URLs you can use the SEOURLMapper.
Example:

```
String patternName = "CanonicalItemURL";
TypedProperty properties = new TypedProperty();
properties.put("storeId", storeId);
properties.put("langId", languageId);
properties.put("catalogId", catalogId);

SEOURLMapper mapperInstance = SEOConfigurationRegistry.singleton().getMapperInstance();
String seoUrl = mapperInstance.constructDynamicURLByPatternName(patternName, properties, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually all these SEO URLs are created by a JAVA class only (internally). You need to check your `wc-server.xml` where you define the `SEOConfiguration`.

There must be a URLMapper class associated with the configuration. By default it's `SEOURLMapper`. Check its methods `constructSEOURL` and `deconstructSEOURL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypedProperty urlProperties = new TypedProperty();
urlProperties.put("storeId", storeId);
urlProperties.put("catalogId", catalogId);
urlProperties.put("langId", languageId);
urlProperties.put("urlLangId", languageId);
urlProperties.put("productId", productId);
SEOURLMapper mapper = SEOConfigurationRegistry.singleton().getMapperInstance();
url = mapper.constructSEOURLByPatternName("ProductURL", urlProperties, null, null, null);
```

The above code would help you in generating Product URL for language ID -> languageId.

We have to pass urlLangId, if we need to have the URL in multiple languages or else it would be always pick up EN urlkeyword.

FYI - ProductURL is the pattern name in patterns XML file.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.